# How to install php 5.5.9 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, php-5.5

I tried with a PPA - `ppa:ondrej/php` but it says

> PLEASE DON'T USE PHP 5.4 OR PHP 5.5. The PHP 5.5 and later are no longer supported with security updates, therefore they are not included in this repository.

Note: I understand it is not preferred to use PHP5.5+ still i wanted to install. Is there is any ppa is available with php5.5.9 with all supported extensions?

Comment: That's a pretty good warning message. PHP 5.5 has been entirely unsupported (not even receiving security updates) for over a year. Why do you want to use it? (Even if you did have a good reason for wanting to use 5.5, which I doubt, you should be using the latest release—[5.5.38](http://php.net/downloads#v5.5.38)—not 5.5.9.)

Comment: I want to use it for one my old project. Which I've written using php 5.5.9

Comment: I _strongly_ advise you to use at least PHP 5.6. You may not to modify your application very much to make it work with 5.6.

Comment: The best approach for working with old code is to run the corresponding Linux instance in a virtual machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Best option

As I stated in comments *I **very strongly** advise you to use a supported version of PHP*. Using outdated versions of PHP means being susceptible to all kinds of security vulnerabilities. Upgrading your application to work with PHP 5.6 may not be very much work.

### Much, much worse option

If you absolutely must use PHP 5.5 (which I **don't recommend**), you should use the latest release ([5.5.38](http://php.net/downloads#v5.5.38)), not 5.5.9. There should not be any breaking changes in 5.5.38 vs. 5.5.9; you'll just get a whole bunch of bugfixes and security patches.

Since PHP 5.5 has reached end-of-life you won't receive any updates to it via any channel, so there isn't much value in installing via PPA vs. building from source. I agree with the stance taken by `ppa:ondrej/php` not to provide PHP 5.5 anymore, and other PPA providers are likely to go down the same path.

If you're confident that you know the risks of using an ancient version of PHP, and accept them (*please don't!*), you can [download](http://php.net/downloads.php) the source code for PHP 5.5.38 from PHP.net and then [build it](http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.php).

### PHP 5.5.9

*Seriously, I beg you, **don't** use this version of PHP. If using PHP 5.5.38 in 2017 is crazy (**it is!**), using PHP 5.5.9 is **complete insanity**.*

Comment: I've written some old projects in php5.5.9 and I wanted to cross check some of the functionality in the older versions. That is the reason I am trying to install php5.5.9. Any how thank you for the quick update.

Comment: I'm here because I'm trying to set up a development environment that matches a production environment which the client won't let us upgrade.